# MySQL still commits after ejb transaction rollback

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, transactions, ejb

I am new to EJB and I am noticing that MySQL incorrectly persists my entities when an ejb transaction rolls back. I implement the SessionSynchronization interface to explicitly see the status of the ejb transaction. Here are the code snippets:

```
@Entity
public class Fan implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    public String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Singer favouriteSinger;
}

@Entity
public class Singer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    public String name;
}

@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class MyApplicationException extends RuntimeException { }
```

This ejb is being called from another ejb (a web service):

```
@Stateful
public class HelloEJB implements HelloEJBLocal, SessionSynchronization {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public String testManyToOneUnidirectionalRelationship() {
        Singer singer = new Singer();
        Fan fan = new Fan();
        fan.favouriteSinger = singer;
        entityManager.persist(fan);

        // Test rollback behaviour
        exceptionalMethod();

        return "Created Singer:" + singer.id + " Fan:" + fan.id;
    }

    private void exceptionalMethod() {
        throw new MyApplicationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterBegin() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> The container just created a new transaction");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeCompletion() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> The container is about to end a transaction");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(boolean committed) throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> Transaction Status: " + (committed ? "Commited" : "Rolledback"));
    }
}
```

After calling 'testManyToOneUnidirectionalRelationship', I got the 'Transaction Status: Rolledback' message, but still found the Singer and Fan entities persisted in the MySQL database.
Kindly help with this problem. Thanks

Comment: What storage engine do you use? MyISAM for example does not support transactions which would explain this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you have set your connection to autocommit=true?

Comment: I use InnoDB storage engine. Is there a way to set autocommit per connection; querying the autocommit variable shows 0.